# Click preprocessing with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I am trying to ask a user for confirmation when it clicks something binded with knockoutjs (via data-bind="click: ..)

I found something named preprocessing, but I didn't make it work.
Here is my not working solution

```
ko.bindingHandlers.click.preprocess = function(val) {
    confirm("Are you sure do you want to click that?");
}
```

link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fn7S8/3/)

PS. Have a look at example nr.2 on this [LINK](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html#example-2-binding-expressions-to-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For call function, that you add to `data-bind="click: ..."` binding and execute any another code, you could use something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.click.preprocess = function (value) {
    return 'function() { console.log("Preprocess Click!"); ' + value + '(); }'
};
```

All that returned by `preprocess` are pasted into `data-bind="click: ..."`, so if you write `data-bind="click: Click"` after preprocess will be transformed to: `data-bind="click: function() { console.log('Preprocess Click!'); Click(); }"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not followed the example correctly, note that the example returns a function as a string:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.click.preprocess = function(val) {
    return 'function(){ console.log(123); }'
}
```

I have edited your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nybryx/fn7S8/8/) to show it working